# If I do not need features from Android 6.0 API 23, do I have to care about runtime permissions?

Tags: android, compatibility

This is an easy question and I would really be helped if somebody would confirm my idea.

There is a new feature/change in Android 6, that are the runtime permissions, where apps do not query for permissions at run time, but instead during the time they really use the featre. It's a great idea, but supporting it would require me to change code and I would rather not code more Java than absolutely necessary.

Hence, if I do not really need the features of API 23 (Android 6) features, can I simply use the API 22 version and keep my code unchanged, yet able to run on Android 6 phones?

My take is that a new Android Version is compatible with at least some previous API versions, and else all apps would need to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hence, if I do not really need the features of API 23 (Android 6) features, can I simply use the API 22 version and keep my code unchanged, yet able to run on Android 6 phones?

TL;DR: you do not need to deal with runtime permissions, but not for the reasons that you cite.

What controls whether your app has to deal with runtime permissions is your `targetSdkVersion`. If that is 23 or higher, you have to handle runtime permissions in your Java code. If that is 22 or lower, you do not, though the user can still revoke permissions through Settings.

`targetSdkVersion` affects some, but not all, features of an API level. Usually, the things that it affects are written up in the JavaDocs for the `Build.VERSION_CODES` value, but for whatever reason, [Google decided not to bother](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#M).

Whether you can *code* to any API Level 23 features is tied to your `compileSdkVersion`. There are many things in an API level that are not affected by `targetSdkVersion`, such as new classes and new methods. In your case, you indicate that you do not need any of this, which is fine. However, `compileSdkVersion` does not affect whether Android 6.0+ requires you to implement runtime permission logic in the Java code; `targetSdkVersion` does.

Eventually, something is going to force your hand to raise your `targetSdkVersion` to 23 or higher. At that point, you will need to "bite the bullet" and deal with the runtime permissions.

Comment: I like that the answer highlights the two different SdkVersion aspects. I checked that I currently compile with 22 and though that I was lucky, but I might even use 23 and simply set the appropriated targetSdkVersion. From a user perspective I like the runtime permission, right now its simply double work.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile your app at API 22, you won't be able to use any feature of API 23. And your app will behave normally on API 23 as it does on API 22.

> If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install the app at all.

[Requesting Permissions at Run Time](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: thank you, this is the confirmation I looked for. It makes much sense. I do not know why people downvoted?

Comment: @CommonsWare, can you please explain because I have tried this.

Comment: @RohitArya: See my answer. A developer can set `compileSdkVersion` to 23 and use API Level 23 features *without* necessarily setting `targetSdkVersion` to 23 and having to deal with the runtime permission code. The rest of your answer is fine; just the first sentence is off.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, I meant `compileSdkVersion`. Thanks for correcting me.